# JS Apexcharts: How to Get Index of Clicked Bar

Tags: javascript, charts, apexcharts

i have a probleme to get the correct index of clicked bar in Apexchar.
my chart is filled by series contians **[100,100,66.66,....,0,0]**, when i click to bar with value **0 **i get index of serie **-1**  and that is not correct
help me please .

see attached image to understand